# How to safely communicate between a JS app and an OAuth2.0 server hosted on the same domain?

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, oauth-2.0

I know the issue of securing connexion between a JS app (let's say just 'app') and an OAuth2.0 server (let's say just 'server') is an age-old question.

---

However, I can not find a lot of information about **the special case where the app and the server are coded by the same entity and stored at the same place** (i.e. same domain, or at least, two subdomains of the same domain).

First of all, as far as the OAuth grant type is concerned, I think the right one is the **Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant**, since the server and the app have the same author. The issue here being that the Client ID and Client Secret are available to the user in the client. This can be dealt with either by developing a proxy on server end or by using short-life tokens and disabling CORS (if I understood correctly). **Is there any other property we can take advantage of as far as security is concerned when server and app have the same author?**

---

My second question relates to **the optional use of a Facebook Login authentication** (or whatever well-known app OAuth login system: Google, Twitter, etc.).

Ideally, I want users to log in using either:

- My-app-related credentials (if they registered without using FB login option)
- Facebook credentials (if they registered using FB login option)

The first log in method is the classical one: upon log in, are sent to the server the user credentials along with the client ID and client Secret, we get back an access token and everything works well.

I must confess I'm a bit lost with the second method: upon login, user Facebook credentials are sent to Facebook server, which responds with an access token, and my app get access to my user Facebook information (such as email address and UID). But **I do not know what to do with this FB information, and especially what I should sent to my own OAuth server** so that:

- **The user gets connected** to my server
- **The connection is secure** (i.e. no one can impersonate the user by only having to get her Facebook UID for instance).

In other terms, there should be something secret related to Facebook sent to my server but I can not figure what.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my second question, so I share it here:

What should be passed on to the server is the Facebook access token, so that the server can :

1. make a request using Facebook PHP SDK and the given token
2. retrieve user data (such as Facebook UID for instance)
3. match it against your website user database (which should have users FB UIDs)
4. actually connects the user if there is a match

Step 1. and 2. can be done nicely with the helper class [FacebookJavascriptLoginHelper](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper/4.0.0) of the FB PHP SDK. In this case, the access token is stored by Facebook Javascript SDK into a cookie that is read server-side by the FacebookJavascriptLoginHelper.